# Wird Chrome service slows down my system (12% CPU usage) and makes it unusable?

Tags: google-chrome, 17.04, cpu

This has been killing me for months. And I think it started at some point after Chrome upgraded. Check the image

[image]

It is always at 12% CPU usage, but it kills my system. For example, when I type, the cursor if first stuck, and then words start appearing with every letter doubled.

I cannot End this process as it keeps appearing. If I kill it, I kill the Chrome itself.

A bit about my machine: i7, 16gb ram, SSD disks,... all impeccable. I also have habit to have chrome open on 5-6 desktops with a few tabs open. However, this does not seem to be an issue as the same 12% CPU usage happen if I have 1 chrome window with 1 tab.

Help guys as I cannot  use it any more, and I do not want to return to Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could help:

Disable Add-Ons

1. Right-click the title bar or press "Shift-Esc" to open Task Manager in Google Chrome. Click "CPU" to see which task is consuming the most resources.
2. Write down the name of the task if it's a plug-in or extension. Select the process and then click "End Process" to close the task.
3. Open "Settings" from the Chrome menu and then click "Extensions," or type "chrome://plugins" (without quotation marks) into the address bar and then press "Enter," depending on which type of add-on is exhibiting high CPU usage.
4. Locate the appropriate extension or plug-in in the list. Uncheck "Enabled" or click "Disable" to prevent the add-on from running.

OR

Reset Google Chrome

1. Click the Chrome Menu on the toolbar and then click "Settings."
2. Select "Show Advanced Settings" from the bottom of the page and then click "Reset Browser Settings."
3. Click "Reset" to revert your browser configuration to default.

Comment: I have "Browser" process on the first place consuming 5% of CPU. I had Skype tab 2% which is closed. However, 12% is still there. There is no any add on consuming CPU.

Comment: OMG it was bloody Skype Web. When I killed this tab, CPU went to 0%. OMG OMG

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any extensions or plugins that could be hogging all of your CPU? If you reset Chrome and/or downgrade do you still get this issue? I also had this, but resetting my Chrome fixed it. (I was on Windows though.)